# When is a general branching process *not* Malthusian?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

I'm reading up on some continuous-time branching process theory and I came across a statement in slide 36 of the following:

http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/?a=5508

If I may be brief, the author basically singles out a class of branching processes called *Malthusian* processes, defined by the fact that there is a number $\alpha$ satisfying
$$ \int_0^{\infty} e^{-\alpha t} \mu(dt) = 1 $$
Where $\mu$ is the reproduction function of the branching process.

**Question:** But when is a process *not* Malthusian?

The only case in which I can think of is the case where the branching process "explodes," i.e. the population size is infinite for some $t$. This is apparently possible with positive probability if $\mu(0) > 1$.

But if we assume that $\mu(0) < 1$, $\mu(t)<\infty$ for some $t>0$, and $\mu(\infty)<\infty$ as is done at the top of that slide, then I am pretty sure this guarantees that the branching process is finite almost surely (from a theorem in Jagers, *Branching Processes with Biological Applications*). What case am I missing?

**EDIT**: Forgot the very important condition that $\mu(\infty)<\infty$. Sorry.

Comment: What if $\mu(dt) = e^{t^2}\,dt$? Still $\mu(\{0\})=0$ in this case, but the integral is infinite no matter what $\alpha$ you choose because the integrand will only ever be locally integrable.

Comment: @AdamHughes: Ugh. Apologies. I left out $\mu(\infty)<\infty$ when I copied the conditions from the slide.